# Pass dynamically created data-tables to another callback function as input in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

The data tables have been created using the following snippet

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="my-tables-out", component_property="children"))
def update_output_div():
    params = ["A", "B"]
    num_tables = 5
    for i in range(5):
        table = dash_table.DataTable(
            id=f"table-{i}",
            columns=([{"id": p, "name": p} for p in params]),  # type: ignore
            data=[
                dict(**{param: None for param in params})  # type: ignore
                for i in range(num_species)
            ],
            editable=True,
        )

        result.append(table)
    return result
```

The callback function that I would like to pass it to is:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("data", "children"),
    Input(component_id="table_<i>", component_property="data")
)
def display_output(rows, columns):
    pass
```

The question is how to implement the latter callback function in order to access all data-tables created in the first function. What component_id should I provide to the input (Not sure about it since I am returning a list in the first callback function).

Accessing single table works, The problem is how to access dynamically created tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `my-tables-out` component id as the input to the next callback function and 'loop' for each table (since it is in a `result` list).

In your current implementation, it does not make sense to have table-1, table-2, table-3, etc. changing the `data` component because it is not possible in Dash to have multiple inputs changing the same output component.